# WCF Generic Repository

Tags: c#, wcf

I am currently working on WCF Server and Client(Winform) application. I have quite numbers of Entities(Models) that  I will be performing CRUD operation. I tried implementing Generic Repository but getting error Value cannot be null Parameter name :Key

My Internface

```
namespace Interface
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        [OperationContract]
        T Add(T t); 
        [OperationContract]
        Task<T> AddAsyn(T t);

        [OperationContract]
        int Count();  

        [OperationContract]
        Task<int> CountAsync();  

        [OperationContract]
        void Delete(T entity);  

       .....

    }
}
```

Implementation

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public Repository()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsyn()
        {

            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public virtual T Get(int id)
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }

   ......
}
```

Service Hosting

```
private ServiceHost _service;
private void StartService()
        {

            try
            {
                _service = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service.Repository<>));
                _service.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

App.Config

```
<services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="debug" name="Service.Repository">
          <endpoint name="Repository" address="Repository" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding" contract="Interface.IRepository" />

          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>

              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9898" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
```

Getting Error
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Comment: And where (include stacktrace!) and when do you get that error?

Comment: When ever i start the server I Get System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key'